# Strange compiler error in Eclipse using AspectJ

Tags: eclipse, compiler-errors, aspectj

I'm newbie with AspectJ (inside Eclipse). I've found a problem coding a simple class which I need to get an input parameter (in this example is a simple value).

```
public aspect TestingAspectJ 
{
    pointcut start(int value) : target(int) && execution(void start(int)) && args(value);

    after(int value) : start(value)
    {
        System.out.println("Hello World! My value is " + value);
    }
}
```

AspectJ Compiler throws an error in "after(int value)": This method must return a result of type int.

- I tried to refresh (F5) + Clean the project and does not work.
- I tried with another example which define the same concept and compiler throws the same error.

Could you help me?

Thanks.

Paco.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The aspect compiles nicely here. Probably the compilation error comes from another class where you do something like this:

```java
int start(int number) {
    System.out.println("Number = " + number);
}
```

I.e. you define a method with `int` return type, but do not return an `int` at all or at least not always like in this erroneous example:

```java
int max(int a, int b, int c) {
    if (a > b) {
        if (a > c) {
            return a;
        } else if (b > c) {
            return b;
        } else {
            return c;
        }
    }
}
```

In this example if `a <= b`, nothing is returned which is a bug. Maybe you did something like in example 1 or 2.

By the way, you do have a bug in your pointcut, but not one which makes it uncompileable, just one which makes it not match any method executions: You need to remove the `target(int)` part because it means that you want to match methods of class `int`, but firstly `int` is defined in the JDK (which is not woven by AspectJ) and secondly `int` is not a class at all but a primitive type. Probably you wanted this:

```java
public aspect TestingAspectJ {
    pointcut start(int value) : execution(void start(int)) && args(value);

    after(int value) : start(value) {
        System.out.println("Hello World! My value is " + value);
    }
}
```